# Auto tagging Google ad URLs

Tags: google-ads-api

If I enable Auto tagging for my Google ad URLs, is the gclid parameter the only parameter that gets added?

Like "?gclid=xyz123"?

No "utm_source" or "utm_medium" or anything else gets added as well?

Reason for confirming is the destination collecting the referral data says they can only handle on key/value parameter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, the auto-tagging functionality will only add a `gclid` Parameter to the click URL.

Note that if you manually add `utm_source` or other GA-specific parameters, they will be overriden by the `gclid` value as far as attribution in Google Analytics is concerned—unless you activate the ["Allow manual tagging (UTM values) to override auto-tagging (GCLID values)"](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033981) option in your GA property's settings.